# ViewPager showing data wrong with RecyclerView

Tags: android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, android-volley

I am trying to show holidays per year(fetched from web service using volley) and for display holiday I used `RecyclerView`. Following is my code:
It overall working but some issues exist in this code.
I don't know what I am doing wrong here ?

```
public class ShowHolidaysPage extends AppCompatActivity implements ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener{ 
        private static final int PAGE_LEFT = 0;
        private static final int PAGE_MIDDLE = 1;
        private static final int PAGE_RIGHT = 2;
        HolidayFragment leftPage = null,middlePage = null,rightPage = null;
        List<HolidayFragment> fList = new ArrayList<HolidayFragment>();
        enter code here
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
           fList.add(HolidayFragment.newInstance("" + (year1 - 1), authToken,      deviceId,yearList));
            fList.add(HolidayFragment.newInstance("" + year1, authToken, deviceId,yearList));
            fList.add(HolidayFragment.newInstance("" + (year1 + 1), authToken, deviceId,yearList));
             leftPage = fList.get(PAGE_LEFT);
            middlePage = fList.get(PAGE_MIDDLE);
            rightPage = fList.get(PAGE_RIGHT);
            init();
            pageAdapter = new MyPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), fList);
            pager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.holiday_pager);
            pager.setAdapter(pageAdapter);
            pager.setOnPageChangeListener(this);
            pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
    }

    @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            mSelectedPageIndex = position;
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            if (state == ViewPager.SCROLL_STATE_IDLE) {

     final int oldLeftIndex = leftPage.getIndex();
                final int oldMiddleIndex = middlePage.getIndex();
                final int oldRightIndex = rightPage.getIndex();

                if (mSelectedPageIndex == PAGE_LEFT) {
                    currentYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
                    Calendar prevYear = Calendar.getInstance();
                    prevYear.setTime(currentYear.getTime());
                    prevYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
                    Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
                    nextYear.setTime(currentYear.getTime());
                    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                    leftPage.setIndex(oldLeftIndex - 1, prevYear);
                    middlePage.setIndex(oldLeftIndex, currentYear);
                    rightPage.setIndex(oldMiddleIndex, nextYear);
                } 

    else if (mSelectedPageIndex == PAGE_RIGHT) {
                    currentYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                    Calendar prevYear = Calendar.getInstance();
                    prevYear.setTime(currentYear.getTime());
                    prevYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, -1);
                    Calendar nextYear = Calendar.getInstance();
                    nextYear.setTime(currentYear.getTime());
                    nextYear.add(Calendar.YEAR, 1);
                    leftPage.setIndex(oldMiddleIndex, prevYear);
                    middlePage.setIndex(oldRightIndex, currentYear);
                    rightPage.setIndex(oldRightIndex + 1, nextYear);
                }
     pager.setCurrentItem(1, false);
    }
    }

     class MyPageAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter  {
            private List<HolidayFragment> fragments;
            public MyPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<HolidayFragment> fragments) {
                super(fm);
                this.fragments = fragments;
            }
            @Override
            public Fragment getItem(int position) {
                return this.fragments.get(position);
            }
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return this.fragments.size();
            }
        }
    }
    this method is in holiday fragment:
       public void setIndex(int index,Calendar year1) {
            this.index = index;
            if(year1 != null) {
                year = ""+year1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                if(year.equals(""+year1.get(Calendar.YEAR))) {
                    String year = "" + year1.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                    yearView.setText(year);
                    if(networkCall.getRequestQueue()!= null) {
                        networkCall.getRequestQueue().cancelAll(getTag());
                    }
                    getHolidays(authtoken, deviceId, yearView.getText().toString());
                }
            }
        }

    public void getHolidays(String authToken, String deviceID, final String year) {
            if(recyclerView != null) {
                if (recyclerView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            if(holidayNotAvailable != null) {
                if (holidayNotAvailable.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                    holidayNotAvailable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }
            if(yearList==null){
                yearList=new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }

            if(!yearList.contains(Integer.parseInt(year))) {
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                networkCall = NetworkCall.getInstance(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                String url = url;
                url += "&year=" + year;
                JsonObjectRequest jsonObject = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        yearList.add(Integer.parseInt(year));
                        try {
                            Map<String, String> holidaysMap = new Gson().fromJson(jsonObject + "", new TypeToken<SortedMap<String, String>>() {
                            }.getType());
                            progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            if (holidaysMap.size() != 0) {
                                if (holidayNotAvailable.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
                                    holidayNotAvailable.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                }
                                LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
                                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                                recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
                                adapter = new HolidayAdapter(holidaysMap, year);
                                recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
                            } else {
                                progressbar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                recyclerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                holidayNotAvailable.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError) {
                        String msg = "";
                        if (volleyError instanceof TimeoutError || volleyError instanceof NoConnectionError) {
                            msg = "Time out Error! Please try again later";
                        } else if (volleyError instanceof AuthFailureError) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), IntroActivity.class));
                        } else if (volleyError instanceof ServerError) {
                            msg = "Server Error! Please try again later";
                        } else if (volleyError instanceof NetworkError) {
                            msg = "Network Error! Please try again later";
                        } else if (volleyError instanceof ParseError) {
                            msg = "Parser Error! Please try again later";
                        }
                        if (!EwUtils.isNullString(msg)) {
                            if (getActivity() != null) {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
                networkCall.addToRequestQueue(jsonObject);
            }
}
```

Its shows pages on swipe left or right correctly but following two issues are exist there now:

1. Three pages forms at a time so when we swipe left or right it again call      the get holiday method which create view while it is already created, So I am unable to know why it recreate the page.
2. when we swipe fast then it shows data wrong.It seems it puts data of another request in another fragment.

I already tried it by using pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1); but is not works and recreate the fragment when it comes to idle state.

I don't know what I am doing wrong here.So please guide me about this.

Answer (score 0):

By default, your ViewPager retains one page left and one page right from the active (current) fragment.

This is, when you go to the third the first is destroyed and the fouth is created like a cache for a better user experience.

You can change your limit calling the method of ViewPager [setOffscreenPageLimit](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit(int))

Regarding to your wrong data: I recommend you to separate the logic in different instances from this class. The problem is that the requests are made asynchronously so you change the page before having the response back and it seems to be messy calling the same piece of code.

I hope this would help you

Comment: Thanks Juan, I tried by setting limit 2 and 3 in  setOffscreenPageLimit() but its not working.Am I doing wrong here ?